# Proper fraction $\dfrac{p}{ab}$, given $(a,b) = 1$, has only one form $\dfrac{a'}{a} + \dfrac{b'}{b} - k$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Proper fraction $\dfrac{p}{ab}$, given $p,a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, (a,b) = 1$; has only one form $\dfrac{a'}{a} + \dfrac{b'}{b}  - k$, where $k$ is the integral part of $\dfrac{a'}{a} + \dfrac{b'}{b}$, and can have integer value  $= 0 \text{ or } 1$, and $a^{'}, b^{'} \gt 0, a^{'} \lt a, b^{'} \lt b$.

*Note* This problem is from Chrystal's Vol. $1$, pg. #$46$.
[image]
Can state for integers $A, B; Aa - Bb = \pm 1$, where $A, B$ can be found by Bezout's identity. So, choose a suitable rational multiplier, which can be $\pm \frac{p}{ab}$, have  $$
\begin{align}
& \ \pm \dfrac{pA}{b} \mp \dfrac{pB}{a} = \dfrac{p}{ab}  \text{ - }\text{   (i) }
\end{align}
$$ Two cases arise based on the sign taken.

Case (a): $pA = lb + b', pB = ma - a'; \text { s.t. }  l,m \ne 0$ Substituting in (i), gives:$$
\begin{align}
& \ \dfrac{p}{ab} = l - m +\dfrac{a'}{a}  +\dfrac{b'}{b} \text{ --  (i) }
\end{align}
$$

As the integral part of $\dfrac{a'}{a}  +\dfrac{b'}{b} \le 1$, & $\dfrac{p}{ab}$ being a proper fraction; must have either equality true: $l - m =0$, or $l - m = -1$.

Case (b): $pA = lb - b', pB = ma + a'; \text { s.t. }  l,m \ne 0$. Substituting in (i), gives:$$
\begin{align}
& \ \dfrac{p}{ab} = -l + m +\dfrac{a'}{a}  +\dfrac{b'}{b} \text{ --  (i) }
\end{align}
$$

As the integral part of $\dfrac{a'}{a}  +\dfrac{b'}{b} \le 1$, & $\dfrac{p}{ab}$ being a proper fraction; must have either equality true: $-l + m =0$, or $-l + m = -1$.

---

Need help in completing the proof.

Comment: But, why? Please help me in improving by telling reason for down-voting. How can I be expected to learn on my own, without any indicator? It is not any hw, and this is my best guess for down-voting.

Comment: Well, the statement as stated makes no sense.  If $k$ is the integral part of $\frac {a'}{a} + \frac{b'}b$ then $0 \le \frac {a'}{a} + \frac{b'}b - k = \frac p{ab} < 1$.  What's worse, if $ \frac {a'}{a} + \frac{b'}b =0$ or $1$ then $k$, the integral part of 0 or 1, is $0$ and you have $\frac p{ab} = 0$ or $1$ which is obvious codswallop.  I'm assuming you means something *ENTIRELY* different.

Comment: Are we assuming $p < a*b$??????

Comment: I see.  You are saying $\frac p{ab}$ is "proper" so $0< \frac p{ab} < 1$. and so there is one $\frac p{ab} = \frac {a'}a + \frac {b'}b - k$ where each $\frac {a'}a$ and $\frac {b'}b$ is "proper" and $k = 1$ the sum is more than $1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: The sum is at max. $1$, and at least $0$, as we are considering the integral part.

Comment: Does the sum = 0 or 1 ?or does it equal $\frac p{ab} + 1$ (which is what $\frac p{ab}$ "is of the form" $\frac {a'}b + \frac {b'}b - k$ means)?  Make up your mind.  It can't be both.

Comment: It is from Chrystal's vol 1 & pg #46, and it is $\frac{p}{ab} = \frac{a'}{a} + \frac{b'}{b} -  (0 \text{ or } 1)$. Now, $k$ is that integer part, i.e. $0$ or $1$.

Comment: @fleablood Please find the image of the page of the book, in the edited OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let me applaud your taste, in working through Chrystal.

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but the piece that he seems to leave "to ingenuity of the reader" is the uniqueness of the resolution. Perhaps the what you are missing is that he apparently expects you to use the division algorithm (cited in his article 11)  to guarantee that is that there is not a second way (for example, in the positive case) to write $pA = l'b+b''$ where $0<b''<b$. The same is true for the negative case. And it appears pretty straightforward that there is then only one possibility for $k$.

Comment: Really thanks for that pointer.

Answer (score 1):

==== new answer =====

By Bezout we know that there are solutions so that

$p = ma + nb$.

Claim 1: there is only one solution where $0 \le m < b$.

Claim 2: If $p < ab$ and $0 \le m < b$ then $-a < n < a$

So if $p = ma + nb$ and $0\le m < b$ and $0 \le n < a$ then

$\frac {p}{ab} = \frac {m}b + \frac na$ and $m,n$ are the unique such integers that allow everything to be proper fractions.

If $p = ma + nb$ and $0 \le m < b$ and $-a < n < 0$ then

$p + ab = ma + (n+a)b$

$\frac p{ab} = \frac mb + \frac {n+a}a - 1$ and $m, n+a$ are the unique such integers that allproper fractions.

I leave claim 1 and 2 to be proven .... below.....

==== old copy ====

If $\frac p{ab} = \frac {a'}a + \frac {b'} b - k$ where $p < ab$, $0 \le a' < a$ and $0 \le b' < b$, then $p = a'b + b'a - kab$.

By Bezout's theorem there  are such solutions.

And it's easy to show that if $p = mb + na$ is a solution that all $p = (m \pm ka)b + (n\mp kb)a$ are the only other possible solutions.

(Pf: That's a standard exercise.

It's obvious that $p = ma + nb \implies (m \pm k*b)a + (n\mp k*a)b = ma + nb \pm kab \mp kab = ma+ nb$ so $p=(m \pm k*b)a + (n\mp k*a)b$ are solutions.

If $p = ja + vb$ let $j = m + j'$ and $v = n + v'$.  Then $p = ma + nb + j'a + v'b$ so $j'a = -v'b$.  But as $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ that means $b|j'$ and $a|v'$.

Let $j' = b*j_1$ and $v'=a*v_1$ so Then $j_1ab = - v_1ab$ so $j_1 = -v_1$ and $p = ja + vb = (m +j_1b)a + (m - j_1a)b$.

So those are the only solutions.)

.....

There are multiple values $m,n$ so that $p = ma + nb$ but perhaps only a few where $m < b$ and $n < a$.

......

So let $p = (m + kb)a + (n - ka)b$.  And assume $p < ab$.

Then $0 < \frac p{ab} = \frac {m+kb}b + \frac {n-ka}a < 1$.

Now there is only one possible integer value of $k$ so that $0 \le m+ kb < b$.

Let $b' = m+kb$.

If $\frac {b'}b = \frac {m+kb}b \le \frac p{ab}$ then $0 \le \frac {n-ka}a < 1$ and $0 \le n-ka < 1$ and $k$ is the only possible integer value that makes that so.  Let $a' = n-ka$.

So $\frac p{ab} = \frac {a'}a + \frac {b'}{b}$ and $a', b'$ are the only integers that make proper fractions where that is so.

But what if $\frac {b'}b = \frac {m+kb}b > \frac p{ab}$? Well, Then $-1 < \frac {n-ka}a = \frac p{ab} - \frac {b'}b < 0$.

So $0 < \frac {n-ka +a}a = \frac p{ab} - \frac {b'}b + 1< 1$. Let $a'=n-(k-1)a$. And $-(k-1)$ is the only integer that will allow $0\le n -(k-1)a < a$.

We now  have $\frac {a'}a + \frac {b'}b -1 = \frac p{ab}$.  And $a',b'$ arethe only integers between $0$ and $a,b$ respectively where this is true.

Comment: Please elaborate the line: "There are multiple values $m,n$ so that $p=ma+nb$ but perhaps only a few where $m \lt b$ and $n \lt a$."

Comment: p = ma + nb have many solutions.  But there is only one solution where $0 \le m < b$..  If $p < ab$ then there is only one solution where $0 \le m < b$. And in that case $-a < n < a$.